# Get list of CPT posts in *current* post's taxonomy term

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I've seen dozens of similar but not quite the same questions - It seems easy enough to do a wp_query and get a listing of posts in a given CPT, and sort by a given taxonomy term. However, what i can't seem to figure out or find info on is how to sort via the current page's tax term.

To explain further:

I have a CPT of "Proposals" each proposal can be categorized as part of the taxonomy of "Packages" On each proposal page, i want a list of links to the other proposals that share this given page's same tax-term.

eg. Proposal 1, 2 & 3, are in Package A.  When i'm on any of these proposals, I should see links to the other two proposals listed.

I'm guessing i'm just one step away but i've been banging my head against this for a day - much thanks in advance.

Comment: The Answer to this issue can be found here:

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2649/displaying-posts-related-to-other-posts-by-a-taxonomy-term

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Packages of the current Proposal using [`wp_get_object_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms) and then pass some/all of those into a `WP_Query`.

```
$terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post_id, 'packages', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'proposals',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'packages',
            'terms' => $terms
        )
    ),
);
$related = new WP_Query( $args );
```

If the current Proposal has multiple Packages, this will return a list of Proposals in any of those Packages. You can add `'operator' => 'AND'` to the `WP_Query` `$args` to restrict it to only Proposals in all the same Packages.

Comment: Thanks for this - though so far it's not returning anything. If i remove the arg for tax_query, it'll return the full list of proposals, so i know that is working.
However, with the tax_query, its pulling nothing - I'm ran print_r on $terms and it's returned an empty array. So it doesn't look like something is working within wp_get_objects_terms.

To give you a bit more information - i'm attempting to run this query on a single-proposal.php page - before the main loop. (which shouldn't matter since i'm running a full wp_query w/ a reset. I'm wondering if $post_id needs to be different?

Comment: Ok replaced $post_id with $post->ID and now i'm returning an array.

Comment: However, wp_query is still returning empty. Something perhaps with the 'terms' => $terms?

Comment: Ok i was actually able to figure it all out via this explaination - http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2649/displaying-posts-related-to-other-posts-by-a-taxonomy-term

Comment: It' seems we might have been leaving out one step - in parsing the terms via get_objects_in_term